# How can I convert string encoded with Windows Codepage 1251 to a Unicode string

Tags: string, delphi, character-encoding

The cyrllic string my app receives uses(I believe) the table below:
[image]

said I believe, because all the chars I tested fit this table.

Question: How do I convert such thing to a string, which is unicode by default in my delphi?
Or better yet: Is there a ready-to-use converter in delphi or should I write one?

Comment: You have to tell us what version of Delphi you have and what data structure holds the input string

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Delphi 2009 or later, this is done automatically:

```
type
  CyrillicString = type AnsiString(1251);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  UnicodeStr: string;
  CyrillicStr: CyrillicString;
begin
  UnicodeStr := 'This is a test.'; // Unicode string
  CyrillicStr := UnicodeStr; // ...converted to 1251

  CyrillicStr := 'This is a test.'; // Cryllic string
  UnicodeStr := CyrillicStr; // ...converted to Unicode
end;
```

Comment: I got the impression that the Cyrillic strings were not available as literals.

Comment: @David: No, I think they are not, but then again, I have never said they are. But you can always 'encode' your 1251 string manually: `var
  UnicodeStr: string;
  CryllicStr: CryllicString;
begin
  SetLength(CryllicStr, 1);
  CryllicStr[1] := char(255);
  UnicodeStr := CryllicStr;
  ShowMessage(UnicodeStr);` Or, even stranger-looking: `CryllicStr := 'ÿ';`. Both approaches will display a `я` character.

Comment: @Daivd: Anyhow, I got the impression that the OP somehow already got a 1251-encoded string...

Comment: Exactly, but probably not in an AnsiString(1251) variable.

Comment: "I got the impression that the Cyrillic strings were not available as literals." That depends on the codepage of your source files.

Answer (score 4):

First of all I recommend you read [Marco Cantù's whitepaper on Unicode in Delphi](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980). I am also assuming from your question (and previous questions), that you are using a Unicode version of Delphi, i.e. D2009 or later.

---

You can first of all define an AnsiString with codepage 1251 to match your input data.

```
type
  CyrillicString = type Ansistring(1251);
```

This is an important step. It says that any data contained inside a variable of this type is to be interpreted as having been encoded using the 1251 codepage. This allows Delphi to perform correct conversions to other string types, as we will see later.

Next copy your input data into a string of this variable.

```
function GetCyrillicString(const Input: array of Byte): CyrillicString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Input));
  if Length(Result)>0 then
    Move(Input[0], Result[1], Length(Input));
end;
```

Of course, there may be other, more convenient ways to get the data in. Perhaps it comes from a stream. Whatever the case, make sure you do it with something equivalent to a memory copy so that you don't invoke code page conversions and thus lose the 1251 encoding.

Finally you can simply assign a `CyrillicString` to a plain Unicode `string` variable and the Delphi runtime performs the necessary conversion automatically.

```
function ConvertCyrillicToUnicode(const Input: array of Byte): string;
begin
  Result := GetCyrillicString(Input);
end;
```

The runtime is able to perform this conversion because you specified the codepage when defining `CyrillicString` and because `string` maps to `UnicodeString` which is encoded with UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

Windows API MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() can be used to convert to and from any supported code page in Windows. Of course if you use Delphi >= 2009 it is easier to use the native unicode support.