# Using 1252 codepage AnsiString in computer with 1251 codepage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, codepages, ansistring

DelphiXE application uses ANSI Armenian characters - they use codes in Extended ASCII character set and do not have special CodePage.
When Computer Active Code Page is 1252 all is OK. 
When Computer ACP is not 1252 (1251 for example) then the values of strings with ANSI Armenian characters change and application does not work in proper way.

We tried to set these variables as AnsiString. No result.

In [his answer David Heffernan used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222615/how-can-i-convert-string-encoded-with-windows-codepage-1251-to-a-unicode-string)

```
type
  CyrillicString = type Ansistring(1251);
```

Which allows string variables be interpreted by Delphi as having been encoded using the 1251 codepage in Delphi 2009.

It doesn't work in Delphi XE.

How we can make Ansistring variables be interpreted by Delphi as having been encoded using the 1252 codepage when computer ACP is not 1252?

Comment: `CyrillicString = type Ansistring(1251)` works fine. Probably your code is broken. Of course, one wonders why you want to use ANSI when you have a Unicode Delphi.

Comment: What you are expected to do is stop using ANSI! If you have some legacy ANSI data then isolate it and don't let it spread in your app. At the point of entry us TEncoding to convert from ANSI to native string. Is there a good reason why you are not doing it like this?

Comment: Thanks David. Now it works. I was not using the word type for the first time and was getting error message. We are still using BDE and all the data is in ansistring.

Comment: As I wrote in my question Armenian Ansi Characters have not codepage. So we can't use TEncoding for converting. I've written my own functions for converting from ansi to Unicode and reverse. Ansi string are needed when composing queries from BDE and they still use ANSI  in some computers where our application is installed.

Comment: All the same, convert it to UTF-16 string as soon as it enters your app. And vice versa on the way out.

Comment: And David, is there such kind of type definition for AnsiChar? ArmAnsiChar = Type AnsiChar(1252) is not working.

Comment: No. An AnsiChar is just an 8 bit char. Same type used for all encodings.

Comment: I agree with David: use AnsiString only at the edges (i.e. when interfacing with Ansi-encoded data), but use UnicodeString everywhere else. And the AnsiChar is indeed the same everywhere. The encoding only determines which AnsiChars belong where in the string, and how they should be interpreted by input and output routines.

Comment: And indeed, Armenian is not supported in a Windows codepage. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmSCII.

Comment: You could always derive your own `TEncoding` class that implements conversions between Armenian and UTF-16 without using codepages, either manually or through an external Unicode library.