# conversion of a string from some codepage to Unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, codepages

I would like to convert a CP-1253 string to Unicode and also perform the opposite conversion as well.

Suppose I have two variables holding the strings, a `MySource1253` and a `MyUnicodeTarget`.

1. I presume `AnsiString` to be the appropriate type for `MySource1253`, while `String` should be suitable for `MyUnicodeTarget`, please correct me if I am wrong.
2. Is there some function in Delphi XE to make these conversions from one to the other and vice versa?

Comment: Which Unicode encoding do you want to use. What form do you have the data in.

Answer (score 2):

Declare:

```
type
  GreekString = type Ansistring(1253);
```

And to convert between them, just use following code:

```
var
  UnicodeStr: string;
  GreekStr: GreekString;
begin
  UnicodeStr := 'This is a test.'; // Unicode string
  GreekStr := GreekString(UnicodeStr); // ...converted to 1253

  GreekStr := 'This is a test.'; // Greek string
  UnicodeStr := string(GreekStr); // ...converted to Unicode
end;
```

See also: [How can I convert string encoded with Windows Codepage 1251 to a Unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7222615/576719).

Comment: When doing the conversions, you have to use explicit typecasts to avoid "implicit cast" warnings from the compiler. Unicode<->Ansi conversions are potentially lossy, so you have to tell the compiler you understand and accept that risk. In addition, the RTL also has `LocaleCharsFromUnicode()` and `UnicodeFromLocaleChars()` functions that operate on character buffers instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just call RawByteStringToUnicodeString and pass your AnsiString as a first argument and the code page (1253) as the second argument.

```
MyUnicodeString := RawByteStringToUnicodeString(MyAnsiString, 1253);
```

Here are the functions to convert from AnsiString(RawByteString) to Unicode and back. They are safe wrappers for the Win32 MultiByteToWideChar/WideCharToMultiByte.

```
uses
  Windows, Math;


function RawByteStringToUnicodeString(const S: RawByteString; CP: Integer): UnicodeString;
var
  P: PAnsiChar;
  pw: PWideChar;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if S = '' then
    Exit;
  if CP = CP_UTF8 then
  begin
    // UTF8
    Result := UTF8ToUnicodeString(S);
    Exit;
  end;
  P := @S[1];
  I := MultiByteToWideChar(CP, 0, P, Length(S), nil, 0);
  if I <= 0 then
    Exit;
  SetLength(Result, I);
  pw := @Result[1];
  J := MultiByteToWideChar(CP, 0, P, Length(S), pw, I);
  if I <> J then
    SetLength(Result, Min(I, J));
end;


function UnicodeStringToRawByteString(const w: UnicodeString; CP: Integer): RawByteString;
var
  P: PWideChar;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if w = '' then
    Exit;
  case CP of
    CP_UTF8:
      begin
        // UTF8
        Result := UTF8Encode(w);
        Exit;
      end;
    CP_UNICODE_LE:
      begin
        // Unicode codepage
        CP := CP_ACP;
      end;
  end;

  P := @w[1];
  I := WideCharToMultibyte(CP, 0, P, Length(w), nil, 0, nil, nil);
  if I <= 0 then
    Exit;
  SetLength(Result, I);
  J := WideCharToMultibyte(CP, 0, P, Length(w), @Result[1], I, nil, nil);
  if I <> J then
    SetLength(Result, Min(I, J));
  SetCodePage(Result, CP, False);
end;
```