# Reading a text file written with a different default encoding

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe7

I have a text file which has been written using `TStringStream` without explicitly pass an encoding. This file has been generated from an Italian computer.

```
var
  Stream : TStringStream;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('Test £');
  try
    Stream.SaveToFile('.\test.txt');
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

test.txt

```
Test £
```

I need to read this file from a computer which has different locale settings but I get a different text:

```
var
  Stream : TStringStream;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    Stream.LoadFromFile('.\test.txt');
    ShowMessage(Stream.DataString);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The showmessage instruction displays the following text:

```
Test Ł
```

(note that `£` <> `Ł`)

I've tried passing `TEncoding.Unicode`, `TEncoding.UTF8` to the `TStringStream` constructor but I get unexpected strings and errors like:

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte
> code page.

Is there any way to recognize the source default encoding (considering locale) and use it for reading the file from a computer with different locale settings?

I mean something like:

```
var
  Stream : TStringStream;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    Stream.LoadFromFile('.\test.txt', TEncoding.EncodingUsedByTheWriter);
    ShowMessage(Stream.DataString);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In principle, it is essentially impossible to determine which 8-bit codepage was used. You can guess, however, especially if you have access to large dictionaries of words. Lesson to be learned: never use legacy 8-bit encodings. Always use Unicode. If you know the source encoding, [that's a different thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948221/conversion-of-a-string-from-some-codepage-to-unicode).

Comment: It is not possible to auto-detect it (at least not with such a short text). Consider this: You get one file from Person A that contains "Test £" and one from person B that contains "Test Ł". These two files are binary identical, so how do you know which one is "Test £" and which one is "Test Ł"? You can't determine that from the file contents alone.

However, if you know the locale that was in use when the file was saved, you can force this with:

TEncoding.GetEncoding(CodePage). The CodePage normally used in Italy is 28591 (ISO-8859-1) or 1252 (Windows-1252). Try these two values.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I'll keep it on mind! In future I'll use `TEncoding.Unicode` only :D

Comment: @HeartWare: I know the locale and `TEncoding.GetEncoding(1252)` answers my question! Thank you!

Comment: You don't need TEncoding.Unicode (it'll double the size of your files). You can just as well use TEncoding.UTF8 (which is also Unicode, but in 8-bit encoding instead of 16-bit endoding).

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is the modern standard encoding.

Comment: @Fabrizio Just be sure you `Free` the `TEncoding` object you obtain from `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` when you are done using it. The `TStringStream` constructor that takes a `TEncoding` has an optional `AOwnsEncoding` parameter for that purpose. `TStringStream` also has another constructor that has an `ACodePage` parameter so you don't have to call `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` directly.

Comment: Many thanks to all, I'll use `TEncoding.UTF8` and will remember to free the encoding if using `TEncoding.GetEncoding`. Keeping on mind about the `TStringStream` constructor's `AOwnsEncoding` parameter. If someone want to summarise all comments I'll be glad to accept it as answer